# how to fix plugin of cloud carousel?

Tags: jquery, geometry

I have found this plugin on the internet and used it for my task, but it have a problem for example i have 4 image of flag, cloud carousel plugin will make these flag turn around in circle, but when it stop the front flag and the back flag do not stop at center, i mean the position of 4 flag is not correct, i do not know how to talk about it more clearly but please look the image you will understand the problem i got. In addition, i am not good at math, i do not know how to calculate like the plugin does. Please have a look a suggest me some solution. Thanks in advance !

here is image of problem :

```
http://www.mediafire.com/i/?onvaklt5kbqgxt8

or

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/imgproblem.png/
```

here is an correct example :

```
http://www.mediafire.com/i/?uqk4c1ndyeo50q2

or 

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/135/examplecd.jpg/
```

here is html code :

```
<div class="circle" id="carousel">
            <img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/flag_spain.png" title="Treatment with Baraclude was generally well tolerated and no patients discontinued treatment due to AEs.1"
                alt="ORIENTE Study (n=190)" />
            <img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/flag_italy.png" title="No major safety issues were recorded; none of the patients had to stop or reduce the dose during the study.2 "
                alt="Italian Cohort (n=418) " />
            <img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/flag_eu.png" title="[Baraclude] was safe and didn’t affect renal function or cause lactic acidosis.3"
                alt="VIRGIL Study - Naïve cohort (n=243)" />
            <img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/flag_hongkong.png" title="There were no serious adverse events related to the drug.4"
                alt="Hong Kong Study (n=222)" />
            <p id="title-box">
            </p>
            <div id="all-box">
            </div>
            <span id="alt-box"></span>
        </div>
```

here is css code :

```
.circle {
    background:url(../images/circle.png) no-repeat;
    /*width:445px;
    height:138px;
    position:absolute;
    top:315px;
    left:288px;*/
    width:650px;
    height:475px;
    position:absolute;
    top:165px;
    left:185px;
}

#title-box {
    background-image:url(../images/title_bg.png);
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 24px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 610px;
}

#alt-box 
{
    bottom: 0;
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
}

.cloudcarousel {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

here is plugin's code that i edit some.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CloudCarousel V1.0.5
// (c) 2011 by R Cecco. <http://www.professorcloud.com>
// MIT License
//
// reflection code based on plugin by Christophe Beyls <http://www.digitalia.be>
//
// Please retain this copyright header in all versions of the software
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

(function ($) {

    // START reflection object.
    // Creates a reflection for underneath an image.
    // IE uses an image with IE specific filter properties, other browsers use the Canvas tag.  
    // The position and size of the reflection gets updated by updateAll() in controller.
    function reflection(img, reflHeight, opacity) {

        var reflect, cntx, imageWidth = img.width, imageHeight = img.width, gradient, parent;

        parent = $(img.parentNode);
        this.element = reflect = parent.append("<canvas class='reflection' style='position:absolute'/>").find(':last')[0];
        if (!reflection.getContext && $.browser.msie) {
            this.element = reflection = parent.append("<img class='reflection' style='position:absolute'/>").find(':last')[0];
            reflect.src = img.src;
            reflect.style.filter = "flipv progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=" + (opacity * 100) + ", style=1, finishOpacity=0, startx=0, starty=0, finishx=0, finishy=" + (reflHeight / imageHeight * 100) + ")";

        } else {
            cntx = reflection.getContext("2d");
            try {


                $(reflect).attr({ width: imageWidth, height: reflHeight });
                cntx.save();
                cntx.translate(0, imageHeight - 1);
                cntx.scale(1, -1);
                cntx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                cntx.restore();
                cntx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                gradient = cntx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, reflHeight);
                gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + (1 - opacity) + ")");
                gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
                cntx.fillStyle = gradient;
                cntx.fillRect(0, 0, imageWidth, reflHeight);
            } catch (e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // Store a copy of the alt and title attrs into the reflection
        $(reflect).attr({ 'alt': $(img).attr('alt'), title: $(img).attr('title') });

    } //END reflection object

    // START item object.
    // A wrapper object for items within the carousel.
    var item = function (imgIn, options) {
        this.orgWidth = imgIn.width;
        this.orgHeight = imgIn.height;
        this.image = imgIn;
        this.reflection = null;
        this.alt = imgIn.alt;
        this.title = imgIn.title;
        this.imageOK = false;
        this.options = options;

        this.imageOK = true;

        if (this.options.reflHeight > 0) {
            this.reflection = new reflection(this.image, this.options.reflHeight, this.options.reflOpacity);
        }
        $(this.image).css('position', 'absolute'); // Bizarre. This seems to reset image width to 0 on webkit!                  
    }; // END item object


    // controller object.
    // This handles moving all the items, dealing with mouse clicks etc.    
    var controller = function (container, images, options) {

        var items = [], funcSin = Math.sin, funcCos = Math.cos, ctx = this;
        this.controlTimer = 0;
        this.stopped = false;
        //this.imagesLoaded = 0;
        this.container = container;
        this.xRadius = options.xRadius;
        this.yRadius = options.yRadius;
        this.showFrontTextTimer = 0;
        this.autoRotateTimer = 0;
        if (options.xRadius === 0) {
            this.xRadius = ($(container).width() / 2.3);
            console.log(this.xRadius);
        }
        if (options.yRadius === 0) {
            this.yRadius = ($(container).height() / 6);
        }

        this.xCentre = options.xPos;
        this.yCentre = options.yPos;
        this.frontIndex = 0; // Index of the item at the front

        // Start with the first item at the front.
        this.rotation = this.destRotation = Math.PI / 2;
        this.timeDelay = 1000 / options.FPS;

        // Turn on the infoBox
        if (options.altBox !== null) {
            $(options.altBox).css('display', 'block');
            $(options.titleBox).css('display', 'block');
        }
        // Turn on relative position for container to allow absolutely positioned elements
        // within it to work.
        $(container).css({ position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden' });

        $(options.buttonLeft).css('display', 'inline');
        $(options.buttonRight).css('display', 'inline');

        // Setup the buttons.
        $(options.buttonLeft).bind('mouseup', this, function (event) {
            event.data.rotate(-1);
            return false;
        });
        $(options.buttonRight).bind('mouseup', this, function (event) {
            event.data.rotate(1);
            return false;
        });

        // You will need this plugin for the mousewheel to work: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel
        //        if (options.mouseWheel) {
        //            $(container).bind('mousewheel', this, function (event, delta) {
        //                event.data.rotate(delta);
        //                return false;
        //            });
        //        }
        $(container).bind('click', this, function (event) {

            clearInterval(event.data.autoRotateTimer);  // Stop auto rotation if mouse over.
            var text = $(event.target).attr('alt');
            // If we have moved over a carousel item, then show the alt and title text.

            if (text !== undefined && text !== null) {

                clearTimeout(event.data.showFrontTextTimer);
                //if (event.type == 'click') {
                $(options.altBox).html(($(event.target).attr('alt')));
                $(options.titleBox).html(($(event.target).attr('title')));
                //}

                //if (options.bringToFront && event.type == 'click') {
                if (options.bringToFront) {
                    var idx = $(event.target).data('itemIndex');
                    var frontIndex = event.data.frontIndex;
                    //var   diff = idx - frontIndex;                    
                    var diff = (idx - frontIndex) % images.length;
                    if (Math.abs(diff) > images.length / 2) {
                        diff += (diff > 0 ? -images.length : images.length);
                    }
                    event.data.rotate(-diff);
                    console.log(-diff);
                }
            }
        });

        $(options.specialBox).bind('click', this, function (event) {
            event.data.rotate(0.5);
        });

        // If we have moved out of a carousel item (or the container itself),
        // restore the text of the front item in 1 second.
        //        $(container).bind('mouseout', this, function (event) {
        //            var context = event.data;
        //            clearTimeout(context.showFrontTextTimer);
        //            context.showFrontTextTimer = setTimeout(function () { context.showFrontText(); }, 1000);
        //            context.autoRotate(); // Start auto rotation.
        //        });

        // Prevent items from being selected as mouse is moved and clicked in the container.
        $(container).bind('mousedown', this, function (event) {
            event.data.container.focus();
            return false;
        });
        container.onselectstart = function () { return false; };    // For IE.

        this.innerWrapper = $(container).wrapInner('<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"/>').children()[0];

        // Shows the text from the front most item.
        this.showFrontText = function () {
            if (items[this.frontIndex] === undefined) { return; } // Images might not have loaded yet.
            $(options.titleBox).html($(items[this.frontIndex].image).attr('title'));
            $(options.altBox).html($(items[this.frontIndex].image).attr('alt'));
        };

        this.go = function () {
            if (this.controlTimer !== 0) { return; }
            var context = this;
            this.controlTimer = setTimeout(function () { context.updateAll(); }, this.timeDelay);
        };

        this.stop = function () {
            clearTimeout(this.controlTimer);
            this.controlTimer = 0;
        };


        // Starts the rotation of the carousel. Direction is the number (+-) of carousel items to rotate by.
        this.rotate = function (direction) {
            this.frontIndex -= direction;
            this.frontIndex %= items.length;
            this.destRotation += (Math.PI / items.length) * (2 * direction);
            this.showFrontText();
            this.go();
        };


        this.autoRotate = function () {
            if (options.autoRotate !== 'no') {
                var dir = (options.autoRotate === 'right') ? 1 : -1;
                this.autoRotateTimer = setInterval(function () { ctx.rotate(dir); }, options.autoRotateDelay);
            }
        };

        // This is the main loop function that moves everything.
        this.updateAll = function () {
            var minScale = options.minScale; // This is the smallest scale applied to the furthest item.
            var smallRange = (1 - minScale) * 0.4;
            var w, h, x, y, scale, item, sinVal;

            var change = (this.destRotation - this.rotation);
            var absChange = Math.abs(change);

            this.rotation += change * options.speed;
            if (absChange < 0.001) { this.rotation = this.destRotation; }
            var itemsLen = items.length;
            var spacing = (Math.PI / itemsLen) * 2;
            //var   wrapStyle = null;
            var radians = this.rotation;
            var isMSIE = $.browser.msie;

            // Turn off display. This can reduce repaints/reflows when making style and position changes in the loop.
            // See http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3          
            this.innerWrapper.style.display = 'none';

            var style;
            var px = 'px', reflHeight;
            var context = this;
            for (var i = 0; i < itemsLen; i++) {
                item = items[i];

                sinVal = funcSin(radians);

                scale = ((sinVal + 1) * smallRange) + minScale;

                x = this.xCentre + (((funcCos(radians) * this.xRadius) - (item.orgWidth * 0.5)) * scale);
                y = this.yCentre + (((sinVal * this.yRadius)) * scale);

                if (item.imageOK) {
                    var img = item.image;

                    //w = img.width = item.orgWidth * scale;
                    //h = img.height = item.orgHeight * scale;
                    img.style.webkittransition = 'transform 0.5s linear, left 0.5s linear, top 0.5s linear';
                    img.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
                    w = item.orgWidth * scale;
                    h = item.orgHeight * scale;
                    //x = x == 214 ? 235 : x;
                    //x = x == 249 ? 235 : x;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        console.log('x : ' + x);
                        console.log('absChange : ' + absChange);
                    }
                    img.style.left = x + px;
                    img.style.top = y + px;
                    img.style.zIndex = "" + (scale * 100) >> 0; // >>0 = Math.foor(). Firefox doesn't like fractional decimals in z-index.

                    if (item.reflection !== null) {
                        reflHeight = options.reflHeight * scale;
                        style = item.reflection.element.style;
                        style.left = x + px;
                        style.top = y + h + options.reflGap * scale + px;
                        style.width = w + px;
                        if (isMSIE) {
                            style.filter.finishy = (reflHeight / h * 100);
                        } else {
                            style.height = reflHeight + px;
                        }
                    }
                }
                radians += spacing;
            }
            // Turn display back on.                    
            this.innerWrapper.style.display = 'block';

            // If we have a preceptable change in rotation then loop again next frame.
            if (absChange >= 0.001) {
                this.controlTimer = setTimeout(function () { context.updateAll(); }, this.timeDelay);
            } else {
                // Otherwise just stop completely.              
                this.stop();
            }
        }; // END updateAll     

        // Create an item object for each image 
        //      func = function(){return;ctx.updateAll();} ;

        // Check if images have loaded. We need valid widths and heights for the reflections.
        this.checkImagesLoaded = function () {

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                if ((images[i].width === undefined) || ((images[i].complete !== undefined) && (!images[i].complete))) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                items.push(new item(images[i], options));
                $(images[i]).data('itemIndex', i);
            }
            // If all images have valid widths and heights, we can stop checking.           
            clearInterval(this.tt);
            this.showFrontText();
            this.autoRotate();
            this.updateAll();

            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                images[i].style.opacity = 1;
            }
        };

        this.tt = setInterval(function () { ctx.checkImagesLoaded(); }, 50);
    }; // END controller object

    // The jQuery plugin part. Iterates through items specified in selector and inits a controller class for each one.
    $.fn.CloudCarousel = function (options) {

        this.each(function () {

            options = $.extend({}, {
                reflHeight: 0,
                reflOpacity: 0.5,
                reflGap: 0,
                minScale: 0.5,
                xPos: 0,
                yPos: 0,
                xRadius: 0,
                yRadius: 0,
                specialBox: null,
                altBox: null,
                titleBox: null,
                FPS: 30,
                autoRotate: 'no',
                autoRotateDelay: 1500,
                speed: 0.2,
                mouseWheel: false,
                bringToFront: false
            }, options);
            // Create a controller for each carousel.       
            $(this).data('cloudcarousel', new controller(this, $('.cloudcarousel', $(this)), options));
        });
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);

// this is my code that implement the plugin above
$(document).bind('ready', function () {

    $("#carousel").CloudCarousel({
        minScale: 0.4,
        xPos: 280,
        yPos: 0,
        xRadius: 260,
        yRadius: 0,
        FPS: 50,
        specialBox: '#all-box',
        titleBox: '#title-box',
        altBox: '#alt-box',
        autoRotate: 'no',
        auted: 0.1,
        bringToFront: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please give the call that you are making to CloudCarousel. You can easily specify the centering parameter in this call.

It is all about computing the xPos correctly. Let me just try to clue you in on how to compute it.

Compute the width of the carousel container (in your case it is 650);

Usually by specifying the xPos as half of the width of your carousel container, you should be achieving the correct results.

Refer to the documentation given on the site http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel-integration.htm. This is quite self-explanatory.